# How to connect wallet with my dapps using yoroi dapp connector.?

Tags: yoroi, decentralized-applications

I am trying to connect my users to my NFT Trading card game with yoroi. Can you provide me with an metamask equivalent for cardano

Answer (score 1):

Currently the only wallet extension that supports Cardano is Nami, but once the PAB comes out Yoroi will have theirs out very quickly.